# Is setting up a payment method too difficult for a junior front end developer

Tags: payment-methods, payment-gateway

So basically my boss has me working on Magento, I am familiar with the admin panel and the basic structure of Magento in terms of where stuff goes and I've been told to set up a payment method with sprite, in my opinion I think it's too difficult he doesn't understand that magento is very php heavy and has a lot of concepts that just go over my head, would any of you guys give this sort of task to a junior front end developer or even just a junior web developer who has little experience in magento development ?

Comment: if possible get the magento extension from `sprite`....

Comment: you want to integrate `sprite` or `stripe` payment method ?

Comment: stripe payment method

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to Stripe, then there is a module for Magento 2 made by Inchoo https://github.com/Inchoo/magento2-Inchoo_Stripe.

If you are using Magento 1, then try search on the marketplace (https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/stripe-2-20742.html) or Google for a bit.

I would recommend to go with this approach first.

Alternatively, there are also Magento development firms out there that would be willing to implement a custom payment method as well (I did some research a few weeks back and found one of them I saw offering to do it for $1000).

To implement the customer payment gateway himself, he will need to understand the concept of a specific Magento version on how to create Module, Controller, Payment Method, and the workflow of the shopping cart process from creating quote, setting up payment, capture payment, submit the quote to make an order, etc. This is doable, but not a trivial task. For someone who doesn't know PHP, it may take several months to get a hold of the minimum knowledge to make the custom module that fully functional.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 0):

Setting up a payment method with Stripe in Magento can be a complex task that requires knowledge of both PHP and Magento's payment processing system. Try searching on the marketplace: https://marketplace.magento.com/magenest-module-stripe-global.html
It may not be the most suitable task for a junior front-end developer or a junior web developer who has little experience with Magento development.
However, with guidance and support from a more experienced Magento developer or an external consultant, it is possible to achieve the desired outcome. It's essential to ensure that the task is adequately scoped, and the developer has access to the necessary resources and support to complete it successfully.